Is 0u defaulting to a signed int?
The following code triggers a signed unsigned comparison warning:
uint16 x = 5;
if(((x) & (uint16)0x0001u) > 0u) {...}

Replacing the if with this eliminates the warning:
if(((x) & (uint16)0x0001u) > (uint8)0u) {...} //No warning

Shouldn't 0u become an unsigned integer and not trigger this warning to begin with?

Please read about usual arithmetic conversions, which is what happens here.

Compilers tend to give warnings for code which may be wrong by accident. If you have an explicit cast like in the second case, a compiler may reasonably decide that the code is intentional and omit the warning.

Changing 0u to just 0 should also eliminate the warning

Everything in C has a type and that includes integer constants such as 0 and 0u.
In the original expression without any casts ((x & 0x0001u) > 0u):
Then x is type uint16_t, 0x0001u is type unsigned int (because of the u) and 0u is also unsigned int.
From there, the usual arithmetic conversions which includes integer promotion apply (see Implicit type promotion rules). On a 32 or 64 bit system which this is (TriCore = 32 bit), the uint16_t is integer promoted to int, since uint16_t is a small integer type (smaller than int).
Then the left expression ends up with types int & unsigned int. They are then balanced as per "the usual" by making the signed operand unsigned. The final expression ends up with types unsigned int > unsigned int - the same types and an unsigned comparison.

In case of ((x) & (uint16)0x0001u) > 0u, we end up with the same but now 0x0001u is explicitly forced a conversion down to uint16_t. We end up with types uint16_t & uint16_t. Both operands are now integer promoted to int, but since they are the same type, no further conversions are made. And so the type on the left side of > is int but on the right side it remains unsigned int. And thus "signed vs unsigned comparison".
(Which is not necessarily an error, but could be. It's brittle and error-prone.)

In case of (x) & (uint16)0x0001u) > (uint8)0u you force the operands further into different types: (uint16 & uint16_t) > uint8_t. The left side is promoted to int as before, but now uint8_t is integer promoted to int too. So you actually end up with a signed comparison even though all operands were unsigned types. Probably not the intention.

Good practices:

Avoid writing expressions that contain implicit type promotions as above, because they are subtle and error-prone.

Avoid casting whenever possible, unless you know exactly what you are doing.
Although on a 32 bit MCU, casting every operand to uint32_t/unsigned int removes all concerns about implicit promotions, so that's one sensible way to deal with it on that particular target.


When dealing with microcontrollers, MISRA C is highly recommended/industry standard. A large chapter in MISRA is dealing with implicit conversion bugs, so by enforcing the rules there you weed out such bugs.

Thank you for the very comprehensive answere, it explained every facet of why the warning was given in my first snippet and now in the second one.
Usually i use MISRA, but i am currently unable to.
As written in my comment, i am still not sure about improving the used macro or not resorting to it at all. But my original question has definitive been answered.

@Johan Part of it may be acceptable as a macro, for example #define BIT_X (1u << 5) would be a fine macro since that's just a compile-time integer constant expression. But #define MASK_BIT_N(data, n) (data & (1u << n)) is just obfuscation - data & (1u << n) is already clear, readable code and the macro just made a mess of it.

The Macro reduces the amount of parantheses for more complex lines of code. I agree in a simple application using the macro is obfuscation but what about multiple mask checks in a single line of code like this:
( ((data & (1u << n)) && (data2 & (1u << m))) && ((data & (1u << x)) && (data2 & (1u << y))) ) versus ( (MASK_BIT_N(data, n) && MASK_BIT_N(data2, m)) || (MASK_BIT_N(data3, x) && MASK_BIT_N(data4, y)) ). Just writing this code i had to check the parantheses again for the first set of code.

@Johan The root of the problem in that example is simply that you are writing way too many expressions on a single line, which is a different issue. And well, parenthesis-related bugs and the like can easily be spotted by adopting a disciplined coding style, example. By lining the expression up underneath each other, typos are trivial to spot. The being said, a more sensible version than any of it would be something like (data & MASK_N) && (data2 & MASK_M) && (data & MASK_X) && (data2 & MASK_Y). Where the masks are #defined integer constant expressions.

On your system, int has more than 16 bits. Hence, not only does int have a rank that's higher than uint16_t, it can also represent every value of uint16_t. Therefore, ((x) & (uint16)0x0001u) is promoted to int.
This happens regardless of the other side of >. The title incorrectly assumes that the signed side is the 0u.
The warning disappears probably because the compiler interprets the (uint8_t) cast as an indication that the signed/unsigned comparison is intentional.

I don't understand, here: '((x) & (uint16)0x0001u)' both variables should be equal to each other, why would a conversion happen at this point?

@JohannesLayla: Because that's what the rules say. And practically, your CPU might not even have a register that can hold a uint16_t.

So everything smaler than 'int' just gets convertet to that, as long as 'int' can represent every value of the variable?
Than the left side gets convertet to int and 0u gets converted to unsigned int, and this is whats generating the warning?
So i can either change 0u to 0 (I tested that, it works) or find what sitze int is on my system and convert everything to unsigned int?

@JohannesLayla: As a style advice, I'd just write if (x & 1). That is much, much clearer. I can immediately see what that means: "if the lower bit of x is set". Until I wrote this comment, I hadn't even realized that your goal was that simple.

I only tried to write the essential parts of the code.
In truth, it is an array of defines to check/set/clear a specific bit looking more like this:
#define IF_BIT_0_SET(x) (((x) & (uint16)0x0001u) > 0u) where the hexcode speicifies the bit that is beeing checked. Albeit yes, for the first bit, this point is a bit maut.
But the Macros go up to the 32 bit and make it easier to read the code.

@JohannesLayla: That adds only more layers of unreadability. The idiomatic form is if (x&1), if (x&2) etc. Setting a bit for the same reason is x |= 4. Resetting a bit is slightly more complex: x &= ~8. If you need more bits, (1UL<<31) can be more readable than 0x80000000u.

@JohannesLayla Writing macros like that is obfuscation. A C programmer is supposed to know the meaning of & and << even if you wake them up in the middle of the night. They do not know wth IS_BIT_0_SET means though, because that's some local macro language - which they are probably not interested in learning. So your macro made the code harder to read for C programmers. We may always assume that the reader of our C code is a C programmer.

@KonstantinMakarov Then IF_BIT_SET(x, 31) causes undefined behavior due to the incorrect macro design. Should have been 1u or far better yet, get rid of the macro.

@MSalters Compound assignment |= is problematic though - if x is a small integer type then you can't avoid the implicit type conversion. Whereas x = x | 4 could be rewritten to get rid of implicit promotions: x = (uint32_t) | 4u;. With compound assignment then no can do.

I am unable to change the Interface of these Macros for now. I have changed the 0u to just 0 for now, this has eliminated the warning. I am not sure if i want to change it not to use macros or if i want to change/improve the macros. Two benefits to the macros remain: Less 'shown' parantheses and beeing less prone to typing errors.
My initial target was to reduce the amount of warnings i was getting (550+) and have managed to reduce these warnings down to 14, these beeing in a part of code i am unable to touch right now.

Re “The warning disappears probably because the compiler interprets the (uint8_t) cast as an indication that the signed/unsigned comparison is intentional”: The warning disappears because, in ((x) & (uint16)0x0001u) > (uint8)0u, both operands of > are int.
